# Can't open Service Fabric project in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: .net, visual-studio, azure-service-fabric, visual-studio-2019

I have a solution with Service Fabric .sfproj project that works well in Visual Studio 2017.

Visual Studio 2019 can't open it. Seems that .sfproj project is unsupported at that moment.

Tried without success to create an empty Service Fabric project in VS 2017 and then open it in VS 2019.

Microsoft Service Fabric installation guide has nothing for Visual Studio 2019: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-get-started

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The documentation you have linked to is evidently out of date. Not only is Service Fabric supported by Visual Studio 2019, Microsoft have [recommended](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureservicefabric/2019/06/11/azure-service-fabric-6-5-release/) that Service Fabric customers switch to VS 2019. I can also confirm from personal experience that it works.

- Install the Azure Development workload in Visual Studio Installer
- Install the latest Azure Service Fabric SDK by downloading it from the page you linked to, or from within the Web Platform Installer in IIS Manager

...and you should be good to go.

Comment: I already have Azure Development workload and Azure Service Fabric SDK 3.4.639. But VS 2019 has no clues of Service Fabric.

Colleague of mine repeated my steps and had the same result.

Comment: Did you install Servicw Fabric AFTER installing VS 2019?

Comment: You are right. I reinstalled Service Fabric SDK and now it works. Repair doesn't sufficient to bring Service Fabric to the newly installed Visual Studio.

Comment: I installed Service Fabric Tools in Visual Studio Installer and then, after opening a solution, Visual Studio simply asked me to install the SDK.

Answer (score 4):

There is a bug related to loading .sfproj files in Visual Studio 2019 when it is side by side installed with Visual Studio 2017. The bug and corresponding workaround may be found [here](https://github.com/microsoft/service-fabric/issues/365).

Comment: When checking to see if the workaround fixed the problem, try re-loading the project. I was just re-opening the solution, seeing the project still saying incompatible, and thinking it was still messed up. Once I actually right clicked and re-loaded the project it turned out that the problem was fixed.